# EF- two WHERE IN clauses in an INCLUDE table produce two EXISTS in SQL sent to server

Tags: entity-framework

I have an `INCLUDE` table that I want to check a couple of values, in the same row, using an `IN` clause. The below doesn't return the correct result set because it produces two `EXISTS` clauses with subqueries. This results in the 2 values being checked independently and not strictly in the same child row. (forgive any typos as I'm typing this in from printed code)

```
    var db = new dbEntities();
    
    IQueryable<dr> query = db.drs;
    
    // filter the parent table
    query = query.Where(p => DropDown1.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(p.system_id.ToString()));
    
    // include the child table
    query = query.Include(p => p.drs_versions);
    
    // filter the child table using the other two dropdowns
    query = query.Where(p => p.drs_versions.Any(c => DropDown2.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.version_id.ToString())) && c => DropDown3.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.status_id.ToString()));

// I tried removing the second c=> but received an error "'c' is inaccessible due to its protection level" error and couldn't find an clear answer to how this related to Entity Framework
// query = query.Where(p => p.drs_versions.Any(c => DropDown2.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.version_id.ToString())) && DropDown3.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.status_id.ToString()));
```

This is an example of the query the code above produces...

```
SELECT *
FROM drs d
LEFT OUTER JOIN drs_versions v ON d.dr_id = v.dr_id
WHERE d.system_id IN (9,8,3)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS C1
              FROM drs_versions sub1
              WHERE d.tr_id = sub1.tr_id
                AND sub1.version_id IN (9, 4, 1))
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 AS C1
              FROM drs_versions sub2
              WHERE d.tr_id = sub2.tr_id
                AND sub2.status_id IN (12, 7))
```

This is the query I actually want:

```
SELECT *
FROM drs d
LEFT OUTER JOIN drs_versions v ON d.dr_id = v.dr_id
WHERE d.system_id IN (9, 8, 3)
  AND v.version_id IN (9, 4, 1)
  AND v.status_id IN (12, 7)
```

How do I get Entity Framework to create a query that will give me the desired result set?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd drop all of the `.ToString()` everywhere and format your values ahead of the query to make it a lot easier to follow.. If EF is generating SQL anything like what you transcribed, you are casting to String just to have EF revert it back to the appropriate type.

From that it just looks like your parenthesis are a bit out of place:

I'm also not sure how something like `DropDown2.KeyBalue.ToString()` resolves back to what I'd expect to be a collection of numbers based on your SQL examples... I've just substituted this with a method called getSelectedIds().

```
IEnumerable<int> versions = getSelectedIds(DropDown2);
IEnumerable<int> statuses = getSelectedIds(DropDown3);

query = query
    .Where(p => p.drs_versions
        .Any(c => versions.Contains(c.version_id) 
            && statuses.Contains(c.status_id));
```

As a general bit of advice I suggest always looking to simplify the variables you want to use in a linq expression as much as possible ahead of time to keep the text inside the expression as simple to read as possible. (avoiding parenthesis as much as possible) Make liberal use of line breaks and indentation to organize what falls under what, and use the code highlighting to double-check your closing parenthesis that they are closing the opening you expect.

I don't think your first example actually was input correctly as it would result in a compile error as you cannot `&& c => ...` within an `Any()` block. My guess would be that you have:

```
query = query.Where(p => p.drs_versions.Any(c => DropDown2.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.version_id.ToString())) && p.drs_versions.Any(c => DropDown3.KeyValue.ToString().Contains(c.status_id.ToString()));
```

Your issue is closing off the inner `.Any()`

```
query.Where(p => p.drs_versions.Any(c => DropDown2.KeyValue.Contains(c.version_id)) 
   && DropDown3.KeyValue.Contains(c.status_id)); //<-- "c" is still outside the single .Any() condition so invalid.
```

Even then I'm not sure this will fully explain the difference in queries or results. It sounds like you've tried typing across code rather than pasting the actual statements and captured EF queries. It may help to copy the exact statements from the code because it's pretty easy to mistype something when trying to simplify an example only to find out you've accidentally excluded the smoking gun for your issue.

Comment: oh my gosh...yep that was it. The parentheses were nested incorrectly. I made the changes you suggested and it was much easier to see. Thank you!  FYSA. I'm using DevExpress components and their Dropdown Editor contains a special KeyValue used to pass list box values back to the server.